# How does a non-upgraded node read a SegWit transaction?

Tags: transaction-verification, segregated-witness, block-validity

I'm trying to understand how my node would interperet a *SegWit* transaction if I do not upgrade.

1. Even if I do not upgrade, I should be receiving the exact same block data as everyone else, correct?

If so, let's say my node receives a block that contains a segwit transaction (i.e. one with a `[marker][flag]` and some `[witness]` data). I'm not sure how my node is going to interpret the data...

2. If the `[marker][flag]` is `[00][01]`, does my node read this as being 0 inputs and 1 output, and still consider this transaction valid?
3. If so, how can it go about recreating the **TXID** from the `[version][txins][txouts][locktime]` if the transaction data is of the format `[version][marker][flag][txins][txouts][witness][locktime]`?

**Basically, I don't understand how my node could receive transactions with `[witness]` data and still consider those blocks to be valid.**

Comment: Thanks Pieter. That both asked (and answered) my question more acutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segwit node will convert transactions and blocks "on-the-fly" while sending them to your non-upgraded node. You will see anyone-can-spend outputs and redeems from such outputs. You will not see any additional flags, witness data and any other segwit stuff.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, Segwit nodes send a stripped-down version of blocks to their connected non-Segwit nodes?

Comment: What happens during relay? Like, if a segwit node sends a segwit transaction to an old node, is that transaction junk after that, or can a segwit node that receives the transaction from an old node reconstruct that data somehow?